# FrameLayout in CoordinatorLayout making toolbar-background transparent to white

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-framelayout

Below is my code:-

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this gives me transparent toolbar as expected, 
As below:-
[image]
But my Framelayout overlap on toolbar so I tried

1. to give top margin to Framelayout
2. using ' app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" '

this code worked and my FrameLayout is not overlaping but my toolbar is turning to white_color.

new Output is as below
[image]

Please help !. what's making my toolbar to be white from transparent background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

- Add a `RelativeLayout` and give background image to that
- Inside that you can have `AppBarLayout` and `FrameLayout` with  `android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout"`

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/amanda">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout"
            android:background="#332"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that .But it also making the toolbar-background white.

Comment: Ok.. let me try again

Comment: @Jayshree toolbar will be transparent add an image to the background of parent relative add a color to your frame layout you will see toolbar shows background color ! Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, the toolbar is transparent when we add background image to relative layout. But in my scenario i don't need the background image, I have pasted all code file in question,
Please check again, and help me to make the toolbar transparent.

Comment: @Jayshree yes the question is lets say you have frameLayout below tool bar so if its transparent what you need to see through it?

Comment: Ok.. I got it Now..Thanks

Comment: @Jayshree as a side note if you need status bar also to be transparent you can use  `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` for you theme

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/robert"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.